# collection.mutable.OpenHashMap vs collection.mutable.HashMap

Tags: scala, scala-collections

For `put` and `get` operations `OpenHashMap` outperform `HashMap` by about 5 times: https://gist.github.com/1423303

Are any cases when `HashMap` should be preferred over `OpenHashMap`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code exactly matches one of the use cases for OpenHashMap. Your code:

```
println ("scala OpenHashMap: " + time (warmup) {  
  val m = new scala.collection.mutable.OpenHashMap[Int,Int]; 
  var i = 0;
  var start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  while(i<100000) { m.put(i,i);i=i+1;};
})
```

The explanation for OpenHashMap ([scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/collection/mutable/OpenHashMap.html)):

> A mutable hash map based on an open hashing scheme. The precise scheme
>   is undefined, but it should make a reasonable effort to ensure that an
>   insert with consecutive hash codes is not unneccessarily penalised. **In
>   particular, mappings of consecutive integer keys should work without
>   significant performance loss**.

My emphasis. Which explains your findings. When to use OpenHashMap rather than HashMap? See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining). From there:

> Chained hash tables with linked lists are popular because they require
>   only basic data structures with simple algorithms, and can use simple
>   hash functions that are unsuitable for other methods.
>
> The cost of a table operation is that of scanning the entries of the
>   selected bucket for the desired key. If the distribution of keys is
>   sufficiently uniform, the average cost of a lookup depends only on the
>   average number of keys per bucket—that is, on the load factor.
>
> Chained hash tables remain effective even when the number of table
>   entries n is much higher than the number of slots. Their performance
>   degrades more gracefully (linearly) with the load factor. For example,
>   a chained hash table with 1000 slots and 10,000 stored keys (load
>   factor 10) is five to ten times slower than a 10,000-slot table (load
>   factor 1); but still 1000 times faster than a plain sequential list,
>   and possibly even faster than a balanced search tree.
>
> For separate-chaining, the worst-case scenario is when all entries
>   were inserted into the same bucket, in which case the hash table is
>   ineffective and the cost is that of searching the bucket data
>   structure. If the latter is a linear list, the lookup procedure may
>   have to scan all its entries; so the worst-case cost is proportional
>   to the number n of entries in the table.

This is a generic explanation. As ever with these things, your performance will vary depending upon the use case, if you care about it, you need to measure it.